# How to install openjdk-14-jdk on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, java, ppa, openjdk, update-alternatives

I already tried to add such repos, but it didn't add 14th version:

```bsh
add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk/ppa
```

I also will need to switch between java versions with `update-alternatives`, I already have few version installed.

If there is no automated way to install it, how to install and configure it manually (in less steps)?

Answer (score 2):

Compiled answer by myself:

Get fresh link from: https://jdk.java.net/14/

Download binary:

`wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14.0.2/205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647/12/GPL/openjdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`

Unpack it:

`tar xvf openjdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`

Move to jvm folder:

`mv jdk-14.0.2 /usr/lib/jvm`

Update java and javac alternatives:

```bsh
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/javac" 3
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/java" 3
update-alternatives --set "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/javac"
update-alternatives --set "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/java"
```

Use to switch between versions:

`update-alternatives --config java`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-14-jdk
```